# how to enable or disable subgrid in jqgrid when using edittype:select based on selected value

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Is it possible to disable or enable subgrid based on the selected value when using edittype:"select" ?

basically it will look like this

```
dataEvents: [
{  
  type: 'change',
  fn: function(e) {
  var thisval = $(e.target).val();
 if ( thisval == 'A' ) { 
 // enable subgrid
     }
 else {
     // disable subgrid
     }
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary solved by using :

```
if (thisval =='A'){
  $('#'+lastsel+' > td').addClass('sgcollapsed');
  $('#'+lastsel+' > td.sgcollapsed >a').show();
}
else {
  $('#'+lastsel+' > td.sgcollapsed >a').hide();
  $('#'+lastsel+' > td').removeClass('sgcollapsed');
}
```